# Dell laptop boot with ethernet doesn't allow for Wifi when disconnected from ethernet

Tags: release-loki, wifi, networking, laptop

When I boot my Dell E5440 laptop, I often have it docked (Dell docking station) and connected via ethernet.  Network settings doesn't show that wifi is an available option when the computer is booted while connected to ethernet.  When the computer is undocked wifi still does not show unless I reboot the machine.

I need to be able to move the computer from docked to undocked and have it switch to wifi.  While an automatic change in adapters would be ideal I don't mind manually connecting, but I don't even have the option.

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` doesn't seem to do the trick either.